# Moving a Menu in Wordpress Admin panel is not working

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am trying to move a menu one level up from the list, by accessing it via the *WP Admin Panel --> Appearance --> Menus*

The problem is, when I try to move the menu by clicking and dragging it like before, it just adds blank boxes below it, like in the screenshot!

I had even upgraded the Wordpress to 3.8.1. But still facing this issue!

Please pardon me if Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this question. Please move to the respective child sites of Stackoverflow, if this question is not apt for here.

Thank you

[image]

### -----------------------

**EDIT**

The following is what am seeing in Google Chrome's Javascript console:

[image]

When I searched in Google, the main cause for this is multiple declaration of jQuery. The above error points to the `Pluto` theme which is being bought.

Comment: Can you add a new item to the menu with the options on the right? Or have you tried creating a menu and see if it works with that?

Comment: Take a look in the dev tools of your browser, and specifically the console, to see if there are any issues with your javascript

Comment: @Howlin: Tried moving existing menu as well as by adding a new menu. Both is giving the same issue!

Comment: @Manolis: "Object #<Object> has no method 'isOverAxis'" is the error that is being shown in Javascript console now. And it points to the jQuery of the theme! When search on Google, some are mentioning that it might be because of multiple jQuery declarations!

Comment: First I would deactivate the plugins one by one and check which one - if any - breaks the functionality. Then, if problem persists, I would try another standard WP theme and if the theme is the problem, I would search the Pluto theme for jQuery conflicts and fix them (http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks guys. Solved it after updating the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was found that, jQuery multiple version conflict was causing this issue.

And got it resolved finally, after updating the Pluto theme. Please note that, I have already updated the Wordpress to the latest version too.

Thanks @Manolis and @Howlin for their help.

Answer (score 1):

I also Facing same Problem.

This problem can be solved directly by Installing this plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/